# Count the Same Columns in Two Differnt Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to count for the same column in two different tables.

So I have two tables, table1 and table2. They both have the column "category". I want to find a way to count category for these two tables and show as the result below.

I know how to do this individually by

```
select category, count(category) as cnt from table1 
group by category
order by cnt desc
```

```sql
select category, count(category) as cnt from table2 
group by category
order by cnt desc
```

Not sure how to combine the two into one.

The expected result should be like below. Please note there are some "category" in table1 but not in table2 or vice versa, for example category c and d.

```sql
 table1  table2
a    4       2
b    4       3
c    3       
d            4
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1c.category, t2c.category) as category,
       t1c.t1_cnt, t2c.t2_cnt
from (select category, count(*) as t1_cnt
      from table1 
      group by category
     ) t1c full join
     (select category, count(*) as t2_cnt
      from table2 
      group by category
     ) t2c
     on t1c.category = t2c.category;
```

You need to be very careful that you aggregate *before* doing the `join`.